# Zynq 7020: some memory is unreadable

Tags: xilinx, zynq

I have a Zynq 7020 chip with 250 MB of DDR memory attached to it put in ECC mode (so 125 MB effectively). It's attached to NAND flash memory and has a series of bootloaders which eventually load VxWorks to run some stuff.

We are about to do a test which will require me to read all the memory, flash, and FPGA configuration memory on the device after execution.

I have another [small] program that I will install via JTAG after the run and have it write out the rest of the RAM, then all the flash and FPGA configuration memory. This program is compiled by the Xilinx SDK and is bare-metal (no OS/bootloader).

When I load this program, I reset the processor (JTAG command), run a `ps7_init.tcl` script that sets all the CPU registers to a good configuration as set by Vivado, load the `elf` file onto the device, then run the processor. This program then tries to read memory starting at the address `0x0`, but it crashes quickly. I told it to start at an address of `1 MB` (`1<<20`) (because I know there's some weird memory map stuff at the beginning, so I tried this just in case) and it reads a little bit more then crashes again.

The crash appears to be the CPU not letting me read these areas of RAM.

Why not? How do I make it so I can read every byte of the `125 MB` of RAM I have?

Answer (score 0):

There is a template project that Xilinx provides that is close to exactly what you are trying to do. It is the "Memory Tests" template, and it runs through attached memory ranges and tests read/write operations. By default it tests DDR memory range and ps7_ram_1. The linker script for the application puts the program in ps7_ram_0, and doesn't test that range since you can't overwrite instruction and data memory for the application.

Code for the template can be found here:

```
<SDK installation directory>\data\embeddedsw\lib\sw_apps\memory_tests
```

I would recommend creating a new project from this template, and changing the memorytest.c file to fit your need.

**To answer your question more directly:** You are likely running into problems with the processors MMU (memory management unit) and cache management. If your application is being loaded into DDR, then it is possible that it is blocking you from accessing application instruction and data memory. If your application is loaded into OCM (like the template) there may be access problems with the memory in cache. If you disable cache using

```
Xil_DCacheDisable();
```

Then you should be able to read from the entire DDR memory space (as long as it exists). Make sure that you configure your applications linker script (*.ld) so that the application knows which memory devices are out there, their base addresses and size.